# javascript: restoring the background color of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my js code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".row.rowstriped:even").css("background-color", "lightGray");

});

var oldBackColor;
function DoRowGold(el) {

    var id = el.id;
    sId = "#" + id;
    oldBackColor = $(sId).css('background-color'); 
    $(sId).css('background-color', '#FFD700');

}

function DoRowNormal(el) {
    var id = el.id;
    sId = "#" + id;
    $(sId).css('background-color', oldBackColor);
}
```

And in my HTML:

```
<div id="someid" class="row rowstriped" onmouseover="DoRowGold(this)" onmouseout="DoRowNormal(this)">
```

and in my css I define an empty rowstriped style. In this way I am sure thatthe jquery code affect only the rows that have this additional class.

css:

```
.rowstriped{}
```

Now I wish that when the document is loaded the rows become of alternate color, but when the user moves with the mouse on a row its background color becomes yellow-gold. Then when it leaves the row with the mouse the background color should return the same as it were according to the striping done by the jquery function.
I have tried to store the old color of the div before I change it in order to reset it in the mouseout event, but with no success.
How can I achieve this?

**Edit I had forgot to give the id in my code sample her, but in my real code there is an id (which is autpgenerated by Razor)

Comment: I don't see any id on your div, so how do you expect `el.id` to work

Comment: why using javascript to change color, you can simply user :hover

Comment: @Carsten this was a code sample, the html is extracted from a razor view, I hadforgotto put the Id in place.

Comment: The striping works and the change of color works in my code, only the background does ntot return to the old color.

Answer (score 0):

@user1238784, here you forgot to give ID of your div element try with given solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".row.rowstriped:even").css("background-color", "lightGray");

});

var oldBackColor;
function DoRowGold(el) {
  
    var id = $(el).attr("id");
    sId = "#" + id;
    oldBackColor = $(sId).css('background-color'); 
    console.log(oldBackColor);
    $(sId).css('background-color', '#FFD700');

}
function DoRowNormal(el) {

    var id = el.id;
    sId = "#" + id;
    $(sId).css('background-color', oldBackColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="row rowstriped" Id="divColChange" style="border: 1px solid red; height:50px; width:50px" onmouseover="DoRowGold(this)" onmouseout="DoRowNormal(this)"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using simple CSS as follows:

```css
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.rowstriped tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.rowstriped tr:hover {
  background-color: gold;
```

```html
<table class="rowstriped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        Smith
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Peter
      </td>
      <td>
        Lucas
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Ammy
      </td>
      <td>
        Joseph
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Molly
      </td>
      <td>
        Hooper
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        James
      </td>
      <td>
        Luke
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: .rowstriped tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
} is css3, but I would like to do it with javascript

Comment: For what exact reason do you  need JS when you can just `CSS` it ?

Comment: css3 is not supported by all browsers?

Comment: Seriously? Unless you are making a website to run IE8 also. Mostly all browsers support CSS3

Answer (score -1):

Ok i decide to go with css:

```
.rowstriped:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .rowstriped:hover {
        background-color: gold;
    }
```